# Symmetry transformation for Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, coordinate-systems

I'm reading about Relativistic Quantum fields from Bjorken and Drell and i was wondering about the equation that most hold for a transformation to be a symmetry transformation. The book states:

We demand that the Lagrangian density is a Lorentz scalar, which during the transformation $\phi_r(x) \rightarrow S_{rs}^{-1}(\epsilon)\phi_s(x')$ stays invariant, meaning:

$$\mathcal{L}(S_{rs}^{-1}\phi_s(x'),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}}S_{rs}^{-1}\phi_s(x'))=\mathcal{L}(\phi_r(x'),\frac{\partial}{\partial x'_{\mu}}\phi_r(x')).$$

What bothers me here is the $x'$ on the RHS and the partial differentaion with respect to $x$ on the LHS. To my mind the relation should be the following:

$$\mathcal{L}(S_{rs}^{-1}\phi_s(x'),\frac{\partial}{\partial x'_{\mu}}S_{rs}^{-1}\phi_s(x'))=\mathcal{L}(\phi_r(x),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}}\phi_r(x)).$$

My guess comes from a simple example of a rotation where the Lagrangian is of the form:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)-V(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).$$

If we make the following transformation:

$$X=xcos\theta+ysin\theta, Y=-xsin\theta+ycos\theta$$

it is easy to show that $$L(\dot{x},\dot{y},x,y)=L(\dot{X},\dot{Y},X,Y)$$

so why doesn't the same form hold for the Lagrangian density described in the book? If anyone wants to read the original it's in chapter $11.4$ and the equations are $(11.52)$ and $(11.53)$

Comment: I can recommend section 2.4 of the conformal field theory book by Di Francesco et al. It's a very nice discussion of Noether's theorem.